# How to use a wildcard in isDefined() or structKeyExists() in a URL?

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I am using ColdFusion 8.0.1.

I am writing a little code in the application file that will look at the URL. If any of a certain type of property is passed, I don't want to update a property in a SESSION structure.

Basically, if a visitor accesses any page that has to do with our registration process, we do not want to update the SESSION.UserInfo.ReturnToURL variable.  For every other page they access, we want to update the variable.

All pages that have to do with the registration process will have "myiq.reg" in the URL. If this were the case, I would use the code below.

```
// DETERMINE WHETHER TO UPDATE RETURNTOURL
if (not structKeyExists(URL, "myiq.reg")) {
    URLString = "http://" & CGI.SERVER_NAME & CGI.SCRIPT_NAME & CGI.QUERY_STRING;
    SESSION.UserInfo.ReturnToURL = URLString;
}
```

But it's not that simple.  My people want to be able to pass other properties that are similar, like this:

```
myiq.reg_confirm
myiq.reg_password
myiq.reg_save
```

I need to be able to soft code these to work with any registration page that they might create in the future.  Basically, I need something like this :

```
if (not structKeyExists(URL, "myiq.reg*")) {
    SESSION.UserInfo.ReturnToURL = URLString;
}
```

Notice the WILDCARD after "myiq.reg". I've tried this, but it doesn't work.

How do I code this so that any page that is access with a URL property that begins with "myiq.reg" is ignored?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could get a structKeyList() of the URL scope, and just do a regex find in that.  Something like:

```
reFindNoCase("(?:^|,)myiq\.reg", structKeyList(URL))
```

(only superficially tested)

You could improve the regex a bit if you wanted to more accurately match actual variable name patterns rather than just any occurrence of myiq.reg in the string.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps...

```
res = '';
params = StructKeyList(url);
for(i=1; i lte ListLen(params); i++) {
  param = listGetAt(params, i);
  if (CompareNoCase(Left(param, 8), 'myiq.reg') eq 0) {
    res = param;
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's a little too verbose.